Undefined Values Even After Passing Props Correctly
I am trying to fetch data and then pass the coaching data as props to another component so that i should render on FE i want to pass the props to the coachingCard Compoenet so that i can use the coaching values to show on frontend
But then props comes undefined
 const [coaching, setCoaching] = useState([]);
 
  const fetchData = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await Service.getCoaching();
      console.log(response.data.coachings);
      setCoaching(response.data.coachings);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error fetching Coaching:", error);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
  }, []);

<div className="flex space-y-6 flex-col">
     
        {coaching?.map((coachingItem) => (
          
          <CoachingCard
            // key={coachingItem.name}
            fees={coachingItem.fees}
            url={coachingItem.url}
            name={coachingItem.name}
            programme={coachingItem.programme}
            location={coachingItem.city}
            ratings={coachingItem.ratings} // Pass the ratings value
            fetchAndUpdateData={fetchAndUpdateData}
          />
        ))}
      </div>

import { Rating } from "@mui/material";
import Image from "next/image";
import React from "react";
import { FaRegEdit } from "react-icons/fa";
import { RiDeleteBinFill } from "react-icons/ri";

type CoachingCardProps = {
  name: string;
  url: string;
  location: string;
  programme: string;
  fees: string;
  ratings: string; // Add ratings prop
  fetchAndUpdateData: () => void;
};

const CoachingCard: React.FC<CoachingCardProps> = ({
  name,
  url,
  location,
  programme,
  fees,
  ratings, // Receive ratings prop
  fetchAndUpdateData,
}: CoachingCardProps) => {
  console.log("name:", name);
  console.log("url:", url);
  console.log("location:", location);
  console.log("programme:", programme);
  console.log("fees:", fees);
  console.log("ratings:", ratings);
  return (
    <div className="flex md:flex-row flex-col space-y-4 md:space-y-0 px-5 py-2 justify-between bg-white">
      <div className="flex space-x-3  w-full ">
        <div className="">
          <Image src={url} alt="coaching image" width={100} height={100} />
        </div>
        <div className="flex space-y-2 flex-col">
          <h1 className="text-lg font-bold">{name}</h1>
          <p className="flex font-medium  text-xs text-[#7B7B7B]">
            <p>{location}</p>
            <span className="mx-1">•</span>
            <p>{programme}</p>
          </p>

          <p className="font-medium  text-xs text-[#7B7B7B]">
            Fees : {fees} INR
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="flex space-y-3 flex-col">
        <Rating name="fullRating" value={parseFloat(ratings)} precision={0.5} readOnly /> {/* Render the Rating component with ratings value */}
        <div className="flex justify-evenly ">
          <div
            className="flex w-8 h-8  rounded-full bg-[#F8FAFB]  justify-center items-center cursor-pointer"
            onClick={fetchAndUpdateData}
          >
            <FaRegEdit size={18} className="text-[#828282]" />
          </div>
          <div className="flex w-8 h-8  rounded-full bg-[#F8FAFB]  justify-center items-center cursor-pointer">
            <RiDeleteBinFill size={18} className="text-[#828282]" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default CoachingCard;


I Want My Data Should properly passed on to another component so that i successfully visible on the FE

I guess, you're sending the wrong fields. For example, the name field doesn't exist under the coachingItem object, it is under the coachingItem.data object. So, sending the props (name, fee, url, etc.) under the data object to the related component like name={coachingItem.data.name} would fix your issue. On the other hand, you can send coachingItem.data as a single prop. Then, get the related fields from the single data prop in CoachingCard component

response.data.coachings Seems to return an array of:
[{
 created at:...
 data:{...}
}]

So when mapping through the array you must do:
      {coaching?.map((coachingItem) => (
        <CoachingCard
          // key={coachingItem.data.name}
          fees={coachingItem.data.fees}
          url={coachingItem.data.url}
          name={coachingItem.data.name}
          programme={coachingItem.data.programme}
          location={coachingItem.data.city}
          ratings={coachingItem.data.ratings} // Pass the ratings value
          fetchAndUpdateData={fetchAndUpdateData}
        />
      ))}


Please check the component from where you are fetching the data. It seems that the response.data.coaching that you are setting to coaching should be response.data  and it is an object, so you need to wrap it in square brackets []. Additionally, it appears that you are not returning the JSX in the component. I believe making these changes would fix the bug.
Take a look at this:
    const [coaching, setCoaching] = useState([]);

  const fetchData = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await Service.getCoaching();
      console.log(response.data);
      setCoaching([response.data]); //  <----- Here, put this "response.data" in a square bracket
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error fetching Coaching:", error);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  return (  // <---- Also check it is like you omitted this return key
    <div className="flex space-y-6 flex-col">
      {coaching?.map((coachingItem) => (
        <CoachingCard
          // key={coachingItem.name}
          fees={coachingItem.fees}
          url={coachingItem.url}
          name={coachingItem.name}
          programme={coachingItem.programme}
          location={coachingItem.city}
          ratings={coachingItem.ratings} // Pass the ratings value
          fetchAndUpdateData={fetchAndUpdateData}
        />
      ))}
    </div>
  );

